# i need to use a visualforce component in an html body in my trigger which sends a mail

Tags: apex, email, visualforce-component, html

I have a trigger which sends a mail on update of the approval status . I am using a HTML part in that trigger to send the mail .

[image]

In place of **x** I want to call my visualforce component which is fetching those values through a controller . What is the format to call the component there

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to create a email template and then pass the template id and what id to fetch the fields values. This makes it easy if you just want to modify the template only in future also the code looks clean. You just have to add these method in Messaging.SingleEmailMessage

1. `setTemplateID(emailTemplate.Id);`
2. `setWhatId(account.Id);//record if
   for merging the fields.`

So the code becomes something like this:

```
public static void sendNotification(Contact){
   Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

   message.setTargetObjectId(contact.id); //The ID of the contact, lead, or user to which the email will be sent

   message.setSenderDisplayName(‘Admin’); 
   message.setReplyTo(‘no-reply@company.com’);
   message.setUseSignature(false); 
   message.setBccSender(false); 
   message.setSaveAsActivity(false); 
  EmailTemplate emailTemplate = [Select Id,Subject,Description,HtmlValue,DeveloperName,Body from EmailTemplate where name = ‘Test Account Alert Email’];
  message.setTemplateID(emailTemplate.Id);
  message.setWhatId(account.Id); //for mergin fields
  message.toAddresses = new String[] { contact.email};
  Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] messages = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> {message};
  Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(messages);

 if (results[0].success) 
 {
   System.debug('The email was sent successfully.');
 } else {
   System.debug('The email failed to send: ' +  results[0].errors[0].message);
 }
}
```

Comment: but i think if we use template it will be mandatory to use set.TargetObjectId() and as I need to pass the external ids as well I cant pass ids in it

Comment: In setTargetObjectId(targetObjectId) you can also add user id. The email will then be sent to that salesforce user

Comment: yes i can do that but I also have external email ids so I cant have their ids

Comment: you can use setToAddresses(toAddresses) that will accept any email list along with setTreatTargetObjectAsRecipient(false).

Answer (score 0):

add `<c:vfcomponentname/>`. If there are any parameters to be passed for instance related contact , use `<c:vfcomponentname contact={!relatedTo.Contact__c}/>`

Comment: I tried adding it ,syntax issue .

Comment: what have you tried and and what is the error ?

Comment: I tried adding <c:vfcomponentname contact={!relatedTo.Contact__c}/> in place of <x> in above code . The error was it cant accept '< '

Comment: You have to break your string.You can try something  like `String approvalDetails='<html>...The following'+<c:vfcomponentname contact={!relatedTo.Contact__c}/>+'Request has been approved....</html>'`